# Change the scale of a chart by the Month in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using Access and I want to change the scale of a chart automatically by the month. The Scale should go from the first to the last of the month. 
For example
In Jan the scale is 1.Jan-31.Jan 
Since it's Feb the scale should change it automatically to 1.Feb-28.Feb.

My code is based on an Excel solution so this might be the problem. There is an Error in this line: *ctlAuf.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber*

This is my code:

```
Sub AdjustVerticalAxis() 

Dim ctlAuf As Chart
Dim MinChartNumber As Date
Dim MaxChartNumber As Date

MinChartNumber = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
MaxChartNumber = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)

Set ctlAuf = Me!ctlAuf.Object
    ctlAuf.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber
    ctlAuf.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I forgot the .value behind minchartnumber and maxchartnumber, but ist still not working

Comment: What is the full text of the error?
What Chart object are you using?

Comment: I tried to start the code with a button but when I hit the button, there is nothing happening. 
I’m working with a bar chart.